# Updating an image in Java Swing shows strange behaviour

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to update an image in Java Swing and tried two different methods of rendering these images.

1. Define a JLabel and set the icon of it
2. Override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function in a custom JPanel and call `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)`

Rendering the first image works as expected in both ways, but if I'm trying to update the image, it doesn't replace but renders one layer above which is a problem, because the images I want to render are semi-transparent, so you can see the others through.
I'm already using the `repaint()` method.

###### Method 1

```java
public void setImage(Image img) {
    this.backgroundLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
    this.repaint();
}
```

###### Method 2

```java
public void setImage(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

I'm thankful for any tips! <3

Answer (score 1):

The first thing line in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` should be

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

This clears the panel, does any background painting if necessary, and any other support functions from the overridden `paintComponent` method.  Otherwise, you will keep drawing images over the previous ones without first clearing them.

Comment: It is actually on top of the method. I only forgot to copy it as well. :)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.  Out of context snippets don't show the complete story.

Comment: For that MRE, either hot-link to images found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556) or create them as the class is being constructed. Another tip: `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);` - ***every*** `JComponent` is an `ImageObserver`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future with the same problem, here is the answer I came up with.
I didn't repainted the full frame, but only the JPanel.
I had to add

```java
frame.repaint();
```

in `setImage()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, without the [mre] it doesn't really help much.  Recommend  you update your answer and use one of the images [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) suggested.